# Terminal Header

Tags: linux, terminal, java

Is it possible to run a java command as soon as the terminal opens and after it displays you have the normal terminal prompt. I have an ascii header i made its a java file and i want it to display every time i open the terminal so it shows as a header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` depending on which shell you're using.

Comment: Where would i add it in the .bashrc?